# Investigating the rate of change of volume of a toilet paper roll unrolling at a constant rate.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, graphing-functions

Constants:

- The horizontal length of the paper roll will not change as it unrolls;
- The inner cylindrical empty space is present with radius **r**
- Paper roll has a radius **R** measured from the center of the empty space in the middle to the edge of the roll
- The roll is being unrolled at a constant rate, however the change in volume and radius **R** isn't constant

What I know:

- I started off by differentiating the formula for the volume of a cylinder with radius **R**. I ignored the empty space in the middle with radius **r** as it is a constant and will disappear during differentiation
- After differentiating what I got was $\frac{dV}{dt} = 2\pi hR(\frac{dR}{dt})$
- However none of the $dt$ functions are constant therefore I cant have an experiment just measuring the radius or the volume over time to find the $dt$ functions value as the other $dt$ function will affect it.

Question:

What is another way that I could approach this problem mathematically to have a constant rate of change for any of the variables listed above or a new variable like the length of the paper that has been unrolled which will increase constantly that has not been talked above. Or is there a way to manipulate the existing variables to at least plot a graph for one of the them?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Great approach! I recommend including thickness of toilet paper roll. Applying conservation of mass, and since density is not changing, total volume of toilet paper is constant. Though if I understand, you want to look at the volume left on the roll. This volume is decreasing at a constant rate, by the amount that is leaving the roll, which is
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = - vwd$$
where $v$ is velocity, $w$ is width (perpendicular to velocity), and $d$ is thickness. Let me know if you had something else in mind.

Comment: @TonyMathew Thanks for the comment. What i had in mind was that if i was to conduct and experiment where I unroll the paper roll at a constant rate and measure the change on radius over time and plot the data, I would end up with a line of increasingly negative gradient. This is because as the roll gets smaller the same oamunt of paper removed results in a greater change in radius and volume. Would this mean dV/dt=dR/dt?

Comment: Define "constant rate". Do you mean constant rotation?

Comment: @user619894 the amount of paper being rolled of is constant over time

Comment: @RaufHeydarli6 Could you explain why removing the same amount of paper over time results in a greater change in volume as the roll gets stronger? I agree this happens to radius

Comment: @TonyMathew as we continue to unroll thew paper roll, the change in volume becomes greater and greater as with the same amount of paper removed the radius becomes more and more smaller. Therefore i would assume that the rate of change in volume and radius be proportional.

Comment: Hmm, I can see the intuitive perspective to that reasoning, though my claim is that the change in volume is constant. Even as the radius gets smaller, the rate of change in volume is the same. As a chemical engineer, I can argue in terms of mass balances and drawing boundaries. But if you're not trained in these perspectives, then this could require a back-and-forth discussion. 

The starting point would be the premise: '*that the same amount of paper is being removed at any time*'. How do you define the *amount of paper*? And how would you calculate the volume of some amount of paper?

Comment: @TonyMathew Im a senior at high school and an aspiring chemical engineer and would love to hear your reasoning behind the claim that the change in volume is constant. The way i think of this is that if we were to unroll the same amount of paper every second, say 5cm, those 5 cm will result in a greater change in radius at stages where the roll is small that 5 cm constitute a lot more that the circumference of the remaining roll so that its radius decreases faster than at earlier stages. As V=piR^2 then the volume would also start to decrease exponentially faster.

Comment: That's great to hear you're aspiring! It is often a math-heavy field, but I feel that would be fine for you. As you wrote, $$\frac{dV}{dt} = 2\pi hR\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)$$
In this expression, only $V$ and $R$ change over time. So the rate of change of volume ($\frac{dV}{dt}$), at some time $t$, depends on both the radius $R$ and the rate of change of radius $\frac{dR}{dt}$ at that time. Over time, same amount of paper unrolled causes $\frac{dR}{dt}$ to be greater in magnitude, so its effect on $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is to increase the magnitude.

Comment: But simultaneously, $R$ has a smaller value over time, so its effect is to decrease magnitude. So $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is both increasing and decreasing over time, and the net effect depends on how strong the two influences are. So it's possible that they could happen to cancel each out and have a net effect of maintaining the value, right?

Comment: @TonyMathew, Although I've never thought of it in that way that R and dR can cancel each other out i don't think it can happen in practice that despite paper being removed there is no volume change. However the dV value does converge to a stop once all the paper has been removed.